# Unable to SSH Permission Denied Public Key

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I am going to try and summarize this as best I can and in as most detail as I can. I deployed my first Django site to a Ubuntu (23.04) server on Linode last night after following this Corey Schafer Python Django [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds&t=4375s). Everything went well and I setup SSH as the tutorial goes over in the video about 23-25 minutes in without issue. I verified everything was working at one point. I exited the server and verified I could get back in via SSH without any issue. Continuing along I spent another hour or two and configured a bunch of other things and made sure the site was up before going to bed and exiting the server. Today I go back to connect to the server and I am met with a message `Permission denied (publickey).`

Knowing I added a firewall after all of this I thought great I probably locked myself out of ssh connections or something. However, after some googling I ran across this modifier `ssh -vT user@IP` and quickly saw that indeed it does seem to be trying to connect over ssh and a connection is made, but it is just failing for reasons which I do not fully understand.

I next tried logging in as the root user via Linodes Weblish and successfully was able to get in and tried to verify a couple of things.

• First I verified that there is a folder at the location `/home/user/.ssh` that contains a file with the key in it.

• Second I verified the permissions by going back through the video walk through for the ~/.ssh/ folder and the contents and ran the following two commands again. `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/` and `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`

The result is the follow for the ssh folder in my home directory.

```
lewpiper@django-server:~$ la -la
total 40
drwxrwxrwx 6 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 14 06:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Jun 14 05:22 ..
-rw------- 1 lewpiper lewpiper  100 Jun 14 05:34 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 lewpiper lewpiper  220 Jun 14 05:22 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 lewpiper lewpiper 3771 Jun 14 05:22 .bashrc
drwx------ 4 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 14 06:09 .cache
drwxrwxr-x 3 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 14 06:37 .local
drwxr-xr-x 8 lewpiper www-data 4096 Jun 14 06:36 Portfolio
-rw-r--r-- 1 lewpiper lewpiper  807 Jun 14 05:22 .profile
drwx------ 2 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 15 06:03 .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 lewpiper lewpiper    0 Jun 14 05:33 .sudo_as_admin_successful
```

The following is the permissions for the file inside the ssh folder in the home directory.

```
lewpiper@django-server:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 12
drwx------ 2 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 15 06:03 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 lewpiper lewpiper 4096 Jun 14 06:37 ..
-rw------- 1 lewpiper lewpiper  749 Jun 14 05:32 authorized_keys
```

• Third I setup a firewall on the server and the current connection types allowed are as follows.

```
lewpiper@django-server:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

• Finally I went to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and for now enabled PasswordAuthentication again until I can get to the bottom of the ssh issue. So for now I can login without having to use the weblish Linode offers. However after doing this I tried to restart the ssh service on the server using the following command `sudo systemctl restart sshd` as the tutorial says you should do when editing this file. Instead got an error `Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.` I recall getting this message last night as well when I was doing the setup for the server and a quick google search turned up that the naming for the service changed and so I tried `sudo systemctl restart ssh` and that seemed to do the trick last night but I wonder if I was incorrect in this.

Below is the sshd_config file as I have it now, but note I did change the password authentication to yes so that I could login without having to use the rsa key generated which is my issue.

```
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

**Questions:**
So my question from here is two part. One did I miss anything that I could do to better troubleshoot why this is happening or I could try? Two if there is no other recommended troubleshooting should I just try and delete my authorized_keys file on the server and secure copy it to the server? Note I am not even positive if that would work because I am not convinced that is even the issue. My hunch is there might be something I am missing or there is more to the `Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.` messaging I mentioned earlier. Also is there any thought to just rebooting the server? Sounds odd but maybe something like the firewall or something gets reloaded and everything is happy then.

Comment: Does `systemctl status sshd` indicate that the service is up and running?

Comment: The name of the ssh daemon service is actually `ssh` not `sshd` (although Ubuntu usually provides an *alias* `sshd` so that either *should* work)

Comment: @Jos it says the sshd service cannot be found. ```Unit sshd.service could not be found.``` If you run the same thing again replacing sshd with ssh it says it is active and enabled.

Comment: That is strange. As @steeldriver said, `sshd` ought to be an alias. `ssh` and `sshd` give identical results on my server.